# Assign value with max date to variable

Tags: sql-server

I have table with fields `ID` and `date`, I need to assign newest date to a variable where `id` is some number.

So if I have dates `2011-01-01` and `2011-02-02` where `ID = 1`, I need to assign `2011-02-02` to a variable.

Comment: your question could be more clear, you just make a series of statements in your post.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```
DECLARE @MAXDATE DATETIME

SELECT @MAXDATE = MAX(DateVal)
FROM YourTable
WHERE ID = @ID
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT @Variable = Date
FROM YourTable
WHERE ID = 1
ORDER BY Date
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternativelly:

```
DECLARE @yourDate DATETIME
SET @yourDate = (SELECT MAX(date) FROM yourTable WHERE ID = 1);
```